# How to stop keyboard input for Edit Control in a Win32 MFC application after Enter key was pressed

Tags: mfc

I'd like my `Edit Control` to stop accepting keyboard input after I press the enter key. I am detecting the `Enter` key being pressed.

Currently, I don't have a handle to the `Edit Control`, so if that's required for this operation, please let me kow how to do that as well.

Comment: You must manipulate the edit control to influence its behavior. To get a handle, you may use [`CWnd::GetDlgItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=vs-2019#getdlgitem). But since you do not tell what you have, it is virtually impossible to help.

Comment: What problem is this trying to solve?

Comment: @j6t Thx, I that's at least a start.

Comment: @IInspectable After the input is entered into the text field, I need to validate it. I want the user to be able to either click the "Apply Changes" button or just press enter after editing the text in the `Edit Control`.

Comment: Pressing Enter when in a single-line edit control invokes the parent dialog's default action. That's default behavior. You don't need to do anything to get that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is clearly more of a workaround, my issue was resolved by using the `GotoDlgCtrl` function to focus on a different element (apply button in this case). This stops the `CEdit` in question from taking further keyboard input.

For getting keyboard input, [DirectX::Keyboard](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Mouse-and-keyboard-input) can be used.

```cpp
if (DirectX::Keyboard::Get().Enter)
{
    CButton* button = (CButton*)GetDlgItem(ID_BUTTON_APPLY);
    GotoDlgCtrl(button);
}
```

Comment: That's an answer to a question different from the question you asked.

Comment: @IInspectable I agree that it's sort of a workaround, but the project deadline is fast approaching. It's good enough for my purposes, but I'd be certainly be interested to see how it's done the proper way.

Comment: Without a question that is specific enough to highlight the desired behavior, it is unlikely for anyone to be able to produce a solution with sufficient confidence. You can either update this question, or ask a new question if the changes would fundamentally change the question.

Comment: @IInspectable, I'm sorry. This "solution" is really a workaround, but solves my issue and I need to move on with the my project. I'll modify my "answer" to be clear about being a workaround.